# Which knots in the Rolfsen knot table are (quasi) positive braid knots?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

A knot is called a *positive braid knot* if it can be presented as the closure of a positive braid. A knot is called a *quasi-positive braid knot* if it can be presented as the closure of a braid which is a product of conjugates of positive generators. 
(See https://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/descriptions/positive_braid.html)

I'm interested in specific examples of (quasi) positive braid knots. Is there any reference on which knots in the [Rolfsen knot table](http://katlas.org/wiki/The_Rolfsen_Knot_Table) are (quasi) positive braid knots?

Comment: Have you used [this](https://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/)? Your properties are listed there (although they aren't filled in for every knot, they are filled in for all $\leq11$-crossing knots).

Comment: In fact that the link in the question goes to the same database that has the searchable database that @magicker72 linked to...

Comment: @magicker72 I didn't know about that. Thank you!